# How can i make a textbox which acts as chat control which accepts the images and text in WPF?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

How to make a `TextBox` control to accept images as well as the text same as the chat application in social networking sites in which if user wants an image to send  then Image should be displayed on `TextBox`, the image gets selected and text continues . How to achieve this in WPF ?

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: You also need to read the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages of the Stack Overflow Help Centre *before* you ask any further questions.

Comment: Ok Sir i will follow it from the next time for sure..........@Sheridan

Comment: @Krrish, you seem to be missing the point. Your question is *not* acceptable on this website at present. You have received 2 out of 5 close votes so far for this reason. If you want your question to be answered, then you'll need to edit your question and dramatically improve it.